# SearchString issue pulling multiple queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get a SearchIndex I've written to query multiple database tables based on the string someone enters.  The number search works correctly but I can't figure out how to get it to search the other tables as well.  This is done in MVC3.

```
 public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString)
    {
        var number = from m in db.Numbers
            select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            number = number.Where(s => s.Numbers.Contains(searchString));

        }
        var assignment = from m in db.Numbers
                         select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            assignment = assignment.Where(s => s.Numbers.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(number);
    }
```

Also as a side node the

```
 select m;
```

what exactly does that do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var mySearchResult = from m in db.MyOtherTables
                          where m.MyField.Contains(searchString)
                          select m;
```

To understand what "m" is doing here, you need to know Linq. There are many good tutorials, you have to google a bit.

1. Here's the [MSDN: LINQ (Language-Integrated
   Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).
2. Here's one of my favorite from Scott Gu [Using LINQ with ASP.NET
   (Part
   1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/14/Using-LINQ-with-ASP.NET-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)
3. And here's another one: [LINQ to Entities: Basic Concepts and
   Features](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features).

**EDIT** Your method may look something like this(just an example):

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string searchString, string tableName)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
    {
        switch (tableName.ToLower())
        {
            case "number":
                var numbers = from m in db.Numbers
                    where m.Number.Contains(searchString)
                    select m;
                //View "Number" should use strongly typed IEnumerable<Number>
                return View("Number", numbers);
            case "assignment":
                var assignments = from m in db.Assignments
                    where m.AssignmentName.Contains(searchString)
                    select m;
                //View "Assignment" should use strongly typed IEnumerable<Assignment>
                return View("Assignment", assignments);
            //Add cases for other each tables
            case "mytable":
                var mytables = from m in db.MyTables
                    where m.MyField.Contains(searchString)
                    select m;
                //View "MyView" should use strongly typed IEnumerable<MyView>
                return View("MyView", mytables);
            default:
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Hope it helps!